# egrep regular expression - same word in the beginning and end

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I want to find all the lines that have the same word in the beginning and in the end of the line.

For example:

```
goodword         fgdlakj 3t sfkl 43lk fkl goodword
bad sfa;lk3t   dgk;gs    34;kl bad334
singleword
```

Desired output

```
goodword         fgdlakj 3t sfkl 43lk fkl goodword
singleword
```

My code is:

```
egrep "(^.+)([ ]+.*\1)$"
```

it does work if the line has more than 1 word. But I want a line containing a single word to match too.

So I tried:

```
egrep "(^.+)($|([ ]+.*\1)$)"
```

and it does not work anymore - and I don't know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose to use `awk` instead:

```
awk '$1==$NF' file
```

The advantage of this solution is that it is way simpler to read, and secondly you can easily change field separator (with `-F` option), so that eg. even the same number of spaces at the beginning and end of the line will match.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works ! thank you. but my teacher didn't teach awk command so I have to use egrep for homework. but I found the solution: egrep "((^[^ ]+$)|((^.+)([ ]+.*\4)$))"

Comment: @Silas2033 please note this will match " a bbb a" (with space at the beginning), but won't single " a". You can consider egrep `'(^[^ ]+$)|(^[^ ]+)([ ]+.*\2$)' file` if you don't want spaces to be matched, or perhaps `egrep '(^\w+$)|^(\w+)( .*\2$)' file` with matching only *word characters*.

Comment: Your (first) `egrep` solution is more complicated than it needs to be, and simultaneously too simple.  Currently it recognizes not only `lock the lock` but also `lock the block`, because you don’t match a space before the `\2`.  But you can eliminate some parentheses, brackets, and plus signs, and reduce it to `egrep '(^[^ ]+$)|(^[^ ]+) .* \2$'`.

Comment: @G-Man , thanks for your comment. my egep is also recognize "lock the block" ,so I fixed it and change in to : `egrep "(^[^ ]+$)|((^.+)(.*[ ]+\3)$)"` . notice that your code is recognize ` lock the block`  too.  `[silas@mars 7]$ egrep '(^[^ ]+$)|(^[^ ]+).*\2$'
lock the block 
lock the block`

Comment: @Silas2033: (1) As you’ve noticed, multi-line comments don’t work.  Since you’re the author of the question, you would be allowed to [edit the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/250376/edit) to say "I tried <ABC command>, suggested by <Fred> in a comment, and I got <XYZ output> as a result.  (2) Are you saying that my suggestion still matches `lock the block`?  Because my suggestion has spaces immediately before and after the `.*`, and the one you quoted back at me doesn’t, and (obviously) spaces are significant here.  (And by the way, you don’t need to say `[ ]`.)

Answer (score 7):

There is really [nice **jimmij**'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250380/89144) but if you insist on **grep**:

```
grep -Ex '(\S+)(.*\1)?' file
```

Comment: Clever; using `-x` to avoid `^` and `$`, and using `?` to avoid `|`.  But not quite clever enough: this matches `active people live longer; that's a fact` because it looks like `act.*act`.  You need to add a `\s` before and after the `.*` and say `grep -Ex '(\S+)(\s.*\s\1)?'`.

Comment: @G-Man Thanx for note. Other way is `'(\S+\b)(.*\b\1)?'` if that OP need.

Comment: `\S` may be GNU-grep only. For more POSIX-ness, I'd use `[[:graph:]]` -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes

Comment: @glennjackman: Is there any practical reason to prefer `[[:graph:]]` over `[^ ]`?

Comment: `[[:graph:]]` would not be correct here. The equivalent of `\S` would be `[^[:space:]]` though more likely you want `[^[:blank:]]` (it's probably not going to make much difference in practice though).

Comment: @glennjackman,  anyway POSIX EREs don't have back-references.

Comment: I used `graph` because `[^[:space:]]` and `[^[:blank:]]` will include the control characters, which I assume are unwanted as "word" characters.

Answer (score 3):

With a POSIX `grep`, an equivalent of `awk '$1 == $NF'` would be:

```
grep -x '[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\([[:blank:]]\(.*[[:blank:]]\)\{0,1\}\1\)\{0,1\}[[:blank:]]*'
```